# Changing Qt style using -style from command line for an application

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have two sources giving several visual examples about possible styles.

Also listed is the following, to adapt the style:

`./myapplication -style motif`

This does not change the style from my standard Ubuntu style, but displays another (ugly, read failed) style in this invocation of the application.

No matter what I write, there is always this unknown failed style while I was under the impression that it would be possible to for instance use the plastique style;

`-style plastique` and `-style Plastique` do not work.

Am I getting the name of the styles wrong, are those styles not available or is something else up?

*Sources:*

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qstyle.html#setting-a-style

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-styles.html

> **Setting a Style**
>
> The style of the entire application can be set using the
>   QApplication::setStyle() function. It can also be specified by the
>   user of the application, using the -style command-line option:
>
> ```
>  ./myapplication -style motif
> ```
>
> If no style is specified, Qt will choose
>   the most appropriate style for the user's platform or desktop
>   environment.

EDIT: As Amartel pointed out below, I do not have these QStyles available. How to get them?

Comment: For listing supported styles do something like this: `qDebug() << QStyleFactory::keys().join(" ");`

Comment: Where would I run that?

Comment: After adding all the neccessary includes, (QDebug, QStyleFactory), it prints the following: `Windows GTK+ Fusion`

Comment: Indeed, these 3 do work.

Comment: Based on the list of supported styles, I'm guessing you're using Qt5. They've made some style changing in it: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/

Comment: FYI, using PyQt5 available styles can be listed with the following one-liner: `python -c "from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyleFactory; print(QStyleFactory.keys())"`